# Good dynamic dns service and client for mac server in 2012?

Tags: osx-lion, dynamic-dns

Apparently DynDNS does not offer free dynamic DNS anymore. My router does ONLY support DynDNS and there is no 3rd-party firmware to change this.
I am searching for an alternative for my requirements,which turns out to be difficult because most google results do not reflect the change and recommend DynDNS.
I would need:

- redirect ssh and some other ports to my home server, a Mac mini
- have a client or some sort of automated solution for OS X
- work in background

I tried no-ip.org, which works fine, except that I have to manually confirm subscription monthly. I am not sure what the best way for client-updating on OS X is. But so far, this seems to be the best option.

My question:

1. Does anyone recommend another dynamic DNS service instead of
   no-ip.org?
2. Any recommendations for dynamic DNS updating from OS X (Lion Server)?

Thanks for reading and any reply!

Comment: You're asking for "shopping" advice on a web service, which is off topic per our [FAQ]. Maybe people in [chat] know more to help you?

Comment: slhck is right, but I'd see if ddclient is available on OSX.

Comment: I'd rather say it's about "computer software" and "personal and home computer networking" which happens to use a webservice. Also, there is another questions here [link] (http://superuser.com/questions/301286/what-is-a-good-dynamic-dns-ddns-service-for-home-use), but it still recommends DynDNS.

Comment: Thanks for finding the other question, we'll close it accordingly. This was asked three years ago when the rules were different.

Comment: I don't want to get into an argument here, but how is this not clearly a question regarding HOME NETWORKING?? Just because it happens to use a webservice? So any software which needs some online counterpart, for example a webpage, is inappropriate? Ok, then...

Comment: No, that's not the primary problem. As I already said, you're essentially asking for others to recommend you something, which is highly subjective. Stack Exchange sites are not a discussion forum, and we don't encourage questions that are polling for a list of answers. Doesn't matter whether they're about actual computer software, a web service, et cetera. I hope you understand that and would like to point you to the specific part of the [FAQ#dontask] again.

Comment: I'm also voting to close for the above reason, even though I *really* want to know a good answer ... them's the breaks.

Comment: As I already said, maybe you can go on the hunt for similar services with people on [chat]. I'm sure that'll be of interest to somebody, considering DynDNS has stopped their free service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**2.** There is a command line client for MacOS - [inadyn](http://www.inatech.eu/inadyn/). Inadyn is configurable and supports different Dynamic DNS providers. Also with some services you can use simple `curl` run as a cron job as a client. `curl` is a command-line tool, and is installed by default on MacOS. For an examples of how to do dynamic DNS with command-line, you can look at instructions provided by [zerigo](http://www.zerigo.com/docs/managed-dns/dynamic_updates) or [net-me](https://www.net-me.net/client). The exact details will vary between different providers.

**1.**
There's a [good list of free dynamic DNS providers](http://talkdns.info/list). I'm too biased to recommend one (see profile ;).